# Java replacing an Icon Image after X time passes

Tags: java, image, animation, replace, icons

IN SHORT: I want to execute a new command 3 sec after the former command had been issued.

THE STORY:
I have an action button that once pressed sets (replaces) an Icon Image (an animaition) on one of the Jlabels.

```
JLabel7.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/iamg/slash.gif")));
```

All I want is to replace the Icon back to the former one after X time passes. In other words I want the new animaition to finish (which is about 4 sec long) and after those 4 sec pass I could set a new Icon.

I realize this can be done with threads unforutly I have no idea how, since all I know is stopping the whole program using something like this:

```
try
{
    Thread.sleep(3000);      
}
catch (InterruptedException ex)
{

}
```

Which is stopping the animation it self as well, instead of waiting till 3 sec pass before executing the new command.. Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). See [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for how to use them. Basically you need to add an action listener to the timer, so that when it fires you can replace the icon.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.. Didn't know about swing timers before, this is perfect.